# Adding TabBarController to splitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have removed the "detail" navigationController from the "master-detail" template to reconnect it correctly to a tabBarController and move the "detail" viewController to the first tab.

Then I got this error:

2014-01-07 21:11:20.364 master-detail[3033:70b] -`[UITabBarController topViewController]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e46e70
2014-01-07 21:11:20.366 master-detail[3033:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-`[UITabBarController topViewController]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e46e70'

So I replace this line in function "application - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions":
 ...

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
```

For:

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
 UINavigationController *navigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
```

But still:
2014-01-07 20:59:38.377 EngLogBook[2955:70b] -`[elbDetailViewController topViewController]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d86ff0
2014-01-07 20:59:38.380 EngLogBook[2955:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-`[elbDetailViewController topViewController]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d86ff0'

What's wrong?

For both iPad and iPhone storyboard. iPhone work just great but iPad is messy.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing does not sound like it will work with standard UIKit tools. You may want to re-think how you're building and laying out your interface. Apple has documents that should provide some guidance.

[Apple Human Interface Guidelines - Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Navigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH53-SW1)

Comment: It's working on iPhone and someone did it, see this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576984/create-a-tabbar-controller-with-a-master-detail-template

But doesn't give a clue on the Detail part.