# UITabBarController inside master of UiSplitViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I want to achieve the same flow as Facebook messenger app, with a tab bar controller inside the master view. See[image]

Ive done exactly as described in this answer 
[Create a TabBar Controller with a Master-detail template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576984/create-a-tabbar-controller-with-a-master-detail-template)

However! It does not work correctly on iPhone, only on iPad. On iPhone, the navigation backwards does not work. The detail pane opens up just like a modal seque with no possibility of moving backwards. What could be the error here? Is this even possible to achieve with standard uisplitviewcontroller? I have tried embedding navigationcontroller in tabbarcontroller also (making navigationcontroller as root in master view), then it works for iPhone but not iPad.

Comment: You might find some info on this issue here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329552/ios8-splitvc-tabbarcontroller-navigationcontroller>

Comment: @Zeezer how did you end up solving this?

Comment: @SAHM Couldnt solve it, redesigned my flow. If you find a solution that works both for iPad and iPhone please post it and I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I ended up getting around this by not using a `UITabBarController`, instead creating a CustomTabBarController which inherits from `UIViewController`. The custom controller has a `UITabBar` at the bottom of its view, and multiple other `UIViewController`s embedded in Container Views. The custom controller sets the `isHidden` property to `true` for of all of the embedded view controller *except* the one which corresponds to the selected tab.

The following is a simple example with two tabs, identified by their tag:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tab1View: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tab2View: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tabBar.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        tab1View.isHidden = item.tag != 1
        tab2View.isHidden = item.tag != 2
    }
}
```

This custom controller should be set to the root of a `UINavigationController`, which itself should be set as the master controller of the Split View Controller:

[image: Storyboard showing custom tab bar controller in a split view controller]

This setup works for both iPad and iPhone:

[image: iPhone screenshot showing split view in combined mode]
          
[image: iPad screenshot showing split view in split mode]

There *are* a few drawbacks to this method:

- The custom tab controller is less easy to work with - adding a new tab requires that you add another embedded view and connect it to an outlet in the controller.
- Setting the navigation item's title and left and right bar button items must be done within the custom tab bar controller, upon tab selection.
- This method uses (I think) more memory than a regular `UITabBarController`, since all of the child view controllers are loaded as soon as the app loads, rather than when they are first shown.
- This setup will lead to the tab bar being hidden when detail is shown in (portrait) iPhone mode. This was what *I* wanted, and is the behaviour in the Facebook Messenger app too, but if you want the tab bar to be permanently visible, this method won't do it.

Comment: Correct if i'm wrong but viewDidLoad gets called on every tab connected to a UITabBarController in a traditional setup. So I don't believe the memory hit in your solution is that different than the first party tab controller provided by apple.